# Identity value generation can only be used with signed integer properties

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I've created a new project using ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 EF 7 and am trying to use dnx to scaffold the dbcontext.

This is the command I'm using:

```
dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "<Connection String>" EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer  --outputDir <ProjectDirectoryToSave> --verbose
```

The command fails with this error:

> Identity value generation cannot be used for the property 'QASourceID' on entity type 'C_QATrackSource' because the property
>   type is 'Decimal'.  Identity value generation can only be used with
>   signed integer properties.

Looking at my database in table `C_QATrackSource` it looks like the identity field is indeed a Decimal data type.  This however hasn't been an issue in older projects using LINQ-to-SQL.  Is there any way to get database first in MVC 6 to work with a table that has it's identity field as something other than an integer?

Comment: Can you change the column's data type (e.g. to bigint)? The problem is probably that its scale in the database is 0 (otherwise it can't be an identity column) while `decimal` in .Net doesn't have a scale specification. So the types don't match. Linq-to-Sql may have been more forgiving in this area, but that also leaves room for errors.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: Yeah if I have to I'll research what impact that might have on our other projects.  I was hoping to avoid changing the database structure but if that's the only way to get this to work then it'll have to do.  I'll see if there is a way to maybe do the scaffolding but exclude those tables.  Thanks

Comment: For the record: EF6 didn't complain either. It's an EF7 issue. I'm not sure if it's intended.

Comment: Ok great, that's good info, thank you.  Should be pretty easy to revert to 6 if needed.

Comment: Please take a look here [identity-value-generation-can-only-be-used-with-signed-integer-properties-after](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870063/identity-value-generation-can-only-be-used-with-signed-integer-properties-after). This seems to be a very similar issue.